# SQL query - calculate estimated cost and actual cost

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the two table with the following structure and data

```
Table 1

Task    Category    Estimated Cost
1       11          90.00
2       11          50.00
3       11          3.00
4       12          70.00
5       12          17.00
6       12          5.00
```

```
Table 2

Voucher     Task    Actual Cost
1           1       17.00
2           1       55.00
3           1       35.00
4           2       16.00
5           4       28.00
6           5       5.00
7           5       12.00
8           6       10.00
```

I need a query that will provide a following result based on the estimated cost and actual cost by category.

```
Result

Category    Estimated_Cost   Actual_Cost
11          143.00           123.00
12          92.00            55.00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Should add your current non-working query to the question.

Comment: I have already try the below query, but it did not result as expected 

SELECT t1.Category, SUM(t1.Estimated_Cost) AS Estimated_Cost, SUM(t2.Actual_Cost) AS Actual_Cost
FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Task = t2.Task
GROUP BY t1.Category

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have to compute each sum separately:

```
select category,
       sum(case when cost_type = 'estimated' then cost end) as estimated_cost,
       sum(case when cost_type = 'actual' then cost end) as actual_cost
  from (select t1.category,
               sum(t2.actual_cost) as cost,
               'actual' as cost_type
          from t1
          join t2
            on t1.task = t2.task
         group by t1.category
        union all
        select category, sum(estimated_cost), 'estimated'
          from t1
         group by category) x
 group by category
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/33e08/1/0

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    e.Category,
    sum(e.`Estimated Cost`) as Estimated_Cost,
    min(a.`Actual Cost`) as Actual_Cost
from
    Table1 as e inner join
    (select Task, sum(`Actual cost`) as `Actual Cost` from Table2 group by Task) as a
        on a.Task = e.Task
group by e.Category
```